# Apply ORDER BY after query and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

Have found similar posts but still stuck - I am trying to apply a sort AFTER I have processed a query and limited the results. My code is

```
select DISTINCT(t.id) t_id, t.cart_id ,tS.id tS_id, tS.created tS_created, t.value, t.transactionType_id tT_id, tS.member_name, outIn, tT.type type

                            from(transaction t)
                            join transactionSummary tS ON tS.id = t.transactionSummary_id
                            left join transactionType tT ON tT.id = t.transactionType_id
                            order by t.id DESC
                            limit 50
```

I have tried doing a sub select and applying the ORDER BY afterwards but get an error saying Unknown column 't.id' in 'field list'.

The above code (ie without the sub select) works fine but the ORDER BY slows it down so much as the table is huge...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're aliasing `t.id` to `t_id`, you need to use the alias in the outer query.

```
SELECT *
FROM (select DISTINCT t.id t_id, t.cart_id ,tS.id tS_id, tS.created tS_created, t.value, t.transactionType_id tT_id, tS.member_name, outIn, tT.type type

    from transaction t
    join transactionSummary tS ON tS.id = t.transactionSummary_id
    left join transactionType tT ON tT.id = t.transactionType_id
    limit 50) x
ORDER BY t_id DESC
```

BTW, the way you wrote `DISTINCT(t.id)` suggests that you think the distinct operation is only being applied to that one column. `DISTINCT` applies to the entire `SELECT` list; if you only want to make certain columns distinct, you must use `GROUP BY` to specify those columns.

Here's a possible way to rewrite the query that may make it faster:

```
select DISTINCT t.id t_id, t.cart_id ,tS.id tS_id, tS.created tS_created, t.value, t.transactionType_id tT_id, tS.member_name, outIn, tT.type type
from transaction t
join (select max(id)-500 maxid from transaction) mT on t.id > maxid
join transactionSummary tS ON tS.id = t.transactionSummary_id
left join transactionType tT ON tT.id = t.transactionType_id
order by t_id DESC
limit 50
```

By filtering down to just the top 500 IDs, the size of the joins and sorting are reduced.

Comment: Aha - makes sense re DISTINCT, thanks for the help...I am still getting only the first 50 rows in the table with that query, what I am looking for is the get the last 50 (ie most recent)

Comment: @user2894986 Add `order by t.id DESC` before the LIMIT in the inner query as it is in your and it will work as you expect.

Comment: @valex That's how it was in his original query, but that's not what he wanted.

Comment: I forgot the `DESC` keyword, I fixed it.

Comment: By moving the LIMIT into the subquery, it picks 50 arbitrary rows, then it orders them. Your original query finds the 50 most recent, but you said you didn't want that.

Comment: Hi, correct - what I'm pretty much wanting is the 50 most recent rows. At the moment as i understand (with my code) the entire table is being sorted, then the limit is applied. if i delete the ORDER BY line the query is instantaneous, but if its there is takes about 10 seconds. This happens after every transaction so its a bit of a pain.

Is there a way to just tell the query to start from the bottom of the table and work up, limiting at first 50?

Comment: Is there an index on `t.id`? That should help. The problem is that the joins may make it difficult for it to use that index for ordering.

Comment: yes there is - unfortunately with the current setup as each day a couple of thousand rows are added it just gets slower and slower. I will play around with the joins and see if i can make do with only querying one table...

Comment: @Barmar  - you're a king amongst men! that works a charm - pops in about half a second, much appreciated...